# jQuery Template injects <!----> on every foreach item? Why?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery templates with Knockout, for some reason when using foreach, `<!---->` is magically inserted between every item. Why is that? And how do I get rid of it?

```
<ol data-bind='template: { name: "list_item_template", foreach: showable }'></ol>

<script type="text/html" id="list_item_template">
    <li class="listItem clearfix" id="list_item_${id}">
         ${title}
    </li>
</script>
```

This results in:

```
<ol data-bind='template: { name: "list_item_template", foreach: showable }'>
 <!---->
 <li class="listItem clearfix" id="list_item_301">Stuff</li> 
 <!---->
 <li class="listItem clearfix" id="list_item_302">Stuff</li> 
 <!---->
 <li class="listItem clearfix" id="list_item_303">Stuff</li> 
 <!---->
 <li class="listItem clearfix" id="list_item_304">Stuff</li>  
</ol>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:
(1) Have you confirmed that you are using the latest version of jquery.tmpl.js?

https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js

And I assume your viewModel is working ok?  Here's the viewmodel I used in my local test.  I assume yours looks similar?

```
var vm = {
    showable: ko.observableArray([
        { id: 0, title: 'foo' },
        { id: 1, title: 'bar' },
        { id: 2, title: 'baz' },
        { id: 3, title: 'bam' }
        ])
};
```

(2) By the way, my understanding is that Knockout is soon going to replace jquery.tmpl with jsRender, so hopefully you're not too attached to .tmpl:

https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

(3) As a workaround, have you considered replacing the use of templates with using knockout itself?  This would remove your dependency on jquery.tmpl. So your template would look something like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="list_item_template">
    <li data-bind="text:title, attr:{id:'list_item_'+id}" class="listItem clearfix" ></li>
</script>
```

Comment: I am using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I have a potential work around.

I don't know why jQuery tmpl injects a comment over each item. However, I'd question whether it really is jQuery Tmpl that's injecting the comment and not KnockoutJS. To verify, try using the template without KnockoutJS, see if the HTML comment still appears.

Finally, be aware that the latest version of [Knockout (1.3 beta)](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/08/31/knockout-1-3-0-beta-available/) has its own native template engine; you may be able to fix this by using the native template engine.